# Styled Components and PlatformColor React-Native 0.63

Tags: react-native

I have this file where I manipulate all colors of my app, I intent use PlatformColor of React-Native 0.63
but ocourrs the error:

[image]

File with colors:

```
  colors: {
    background: '#000',
    text: '#fff',
    subText: '#f27b35',
    red: '#d32f2f',
    green: '#388e3c',
    primary: '#353132',
    second: '#f22973',
    third: '#d09c44',
    notify: '#BF343F',
    warning: '#d09c44',
    gray: '#ccc',
    inactive: '#626262',
    icons: '#f22973',
    status: {
      orcamento: '#1976D2',
      aguardando: '#FF5722',
      recebido: '#FFC107',
      processado: '#689F38',
      pago: '#388E3C',
      faturado: '#8BC34A',
      enviado: '#673AB7',
      encerrado: '#607D8B',
    },
  },
  barStyle: 'light-content',
};
```

Comment: Have you found a work-around by any chance?

Comment: Hi Oliver, don't unfortunately not.

Comment: How are you actually invoking `PlatformColor`? Or are you not calling it yourself and some third-party module is?